# Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

my build.gradle:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.g"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 83
    versionName "9.2"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.2.0'
}
repositories {
    google()
    //... others
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Remove** this line in the `app/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'   
}
```

and **move** it in the **top-level** `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        //....
    }
}
```